# How do direct nginx error handling to project folder?

Tags: nginx, flask, raspberry-pi

I have created custom files for error handling (404, 50x, etc) and have them as ordinary html in error/templates directory wehere rest of my project is.

Nginx runs fine and I can access my page. The issue is that my error pages aren't working e.g. when visiting /nopage in my browser I get the default message. Same with internal server error.

How do I fix this?

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;

    recursive_error_pages on;

    error_page 404 /404.html;
    location = /404.html {
        root   /home/pi/pathtoproject/error/templates;
        internal;
    }
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /home/pi/pathtoproject/error/templates;
        internal;
    }
}
```

Comment: The configuration fragment in your question does not indicate how the rest of your site is served. Are there other `location` or `root` statements? If the site is entirely static, check the error log and check file permissions. If the site uses `fastcgi_pass` or `proxy_pass` make sure that you are intercepting errors from upstream.

Comment: I'm fairly new to this so I tried searching for fastcgi_pass and proxy_pass, but could not proceed much. Can you explain more?